# CSS, errores de renderizado, sombras negras aparecen de forma aleatorias

Tags: css, reactjs, img

Hola a todos estoy con una app hecha en react, un todolist, y estoy empezando a dar estilos y me está frustrando mucho no entender un error de renderizado en el css.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No son sombras negras como tal, es el fondo que de alguna forma no se está renderizando bien, **ocurre en todos los navegadores**.

La imagen es un png y tiene una propiedad que se llama  `filter: drop-shadow(0 0 100px #00c9a7);`
lo que hace el efecto ese verde de fondo tan chulo. No es la primera vez que uso esta propiedad, esto no me había pasado antes.

Sin embargo cualquier cosa que haya a los alrededores produce el bug visual que veis en la imagen, lo peor es que lo hace de forma aleatoria, no siempre ocurre, y no siempre es la misma forma.

También si tengo alguna animación, o botón, y hago hover u onClick sobre estos elementos, también se produce el mismo error de renderizado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve probando a ver si dando posiciones relativas y absolutas a los elementos, colocando siempre la imagen y su contenedor por encima de todo con `z-Index: 999999999;` solucionaba algo, pero queva.

No sé si el error puede ser de los componentes de React, o de estilos de posicionamiento, o del propio despliegue del localHost, y quizás haciendo un deploy a producción estos errores se van (lo dudo). Es todo tan aleatorio que me cuesta hacerle un seguimiento.

```
.notes-empty-img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.notes-empty-img img{
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 100px #00c9a7);
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .notes-empty-img{
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
    }
}
```

¿Os ha pasado alguna vez?

Un saludo!

Comment: ¿Revisaste con las *developers tools* si no es algún elemento que se está superponiendo? Más que un error de renderizado, parece un elemento mal posicionado, pero eso sólo lo puedes confirmar tú con las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador. Lo que adjuntas no es suficiente para reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Hola Jaime, sí he comprobado que nada se superpusiera a la imagen, y es lo que comento, no siempre ocurre, y cuando ocurre es de forma aleatoria. Al final lo que haré será bajarle la distancia al sombreado para camuflar el error ..